# Installing existing Windows 7 on one computer to a new computer

Tags: windows-7, operating-systems

I'm looking to upgrade my computer and I currently have Windows 7 Home Premium installed on a HP Pavilion Elite. It didn't come with Windows 7 disks just the Factory Image partition.

My new computer would be a custom build with SSD and I'm wondering how I would go about installing Windows onto the new machine as I have no disks to install it directly.

Comment: I don't understand...just install it. Unless, are you saying that you want to transfer windows from the HP to your new computer?

Comment: @joe Sorry if I wasn't clear. I don't have any windows disks, and the new computer won't include an OS, so I want to know how I can install my current Windows 7 license on the new computer. Preferably I wouldn't want to do a fresh install of Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This almost never works properly.  Usually those Windows licenses are bound to the computer you receive them on.  Even if somehow you managed to get it onto the new machine, the chances of it working are SLIM.  And even THEN, you wouldn't actually have a legal license for it, as it is not the HP that it came installed on.

I would recommend that you do the right thing for your computing experience, and buy a new license of Windows 7 for your new computer.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows license will get locked to your mobo, so you won't be able to install windows on the new machine and use the same product key.....

Answer (score 1):

You go out and buy a copy of Windows to install on your new computer. Your existing
Windows that came pre-installed is locked to the computer it came on, and can't be used
on another machine (barring illegal hacks).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, didn't realize the license was bound to the computer. Figured it would work the same way as if I had bought the disks.